# Creating a multidimensional array from separate variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have a number of variables that store a year, month and series of dates for that month (there are 2 of these for 2 separate months). I then need to incorporate these into what I believe is a multidimensional array (haven't worked with these types of arrays before). Here's my code that has the variables:

```
    // Set the default timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');


    $month1 = date('m');
    $year1 = date('Y');
    $dates1 = '3 5 6 10 12 13 17 19 20 24 26 27 31';

    $month2 = date('m', strtotime('first day of next month')) ;
    $year2 = date('Y', strtotime('first day of next month')) ;
    $dates2 = '10 15 26';
```

Using Dec 10, 2013 as the current date and the above list of dates I then need to end up with an array in this format:

```
array("year" => array("month" => array(days)));
```

that would look like this:

```
$daysArray = array ("2013" => array("12" => array(3,5,6,10,12,13,17,19,20,24,26,27,31)), "2014" => array("1" => array(10,15,26)));
```

I'm not sure how to convert these 6 variables into a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering a few edge cases as well (same year etc), i think this is a rather simple (readable) solution:

```
// Sample data
$month1 = 12;
$year1 = 2013;
$dates1 = '3 5 6 10 12 13 17 19 20 24 26 27 31';

$month2 = 1;
$year2 = 2014;
$dates2 = '10 15 26';


$result = combineDateArrays(createDateArray($year1, $month1, $dates1), createDateArray($year2, $month2, $dates2));

function createDateArray($year, $month, $dates) {
    return array($year=>array($month=>explode(" ", $dates)));
}

function combineDateArrays($dateArray1, $dateArray2) {
    foreach($dateArray2 as $year=>$months) {
        foreach($months as $month=>$days) {
            if (!isset($dateArray1[$year])) $dateArray1[$year] = array();
            $dateArray1[$year][$month] = $days;
        }
    }

    return $dateArray1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronald Swets - that's working well. I need to keep the leading zeros for the month numbers [I'm using $month1 = date('m') ]. Can I keep the leading zeros in the array?

Comment: You can keep leading zeros, but you have to make sure everything is a string and not an integer (number). You can enforce this by concatenating an emptry string before the numbers, or cast to string

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from a string using `explode`:

```
$daysArray = array($year1 => $month1 => explode(' ', $dates1), $year2 => $month2 => explode(' ', $dates2));
```